# How can we change the row height base on a condition in Nebula NatTable?

Tags: nattable, nebula

I want to change the row height of some rows. How can we do it? Can you give me some guide?

Comment: Based on what condition. There is no mechanism to set the row height based on a condition like a label for example.

Comment: Thanks! Example: I want the first row have a double height. The first row is a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the row height to a fixed value, e.g. double the height of a specific row, use the `DataLayer` API.

```
dataLayer.setRowHeightByPosition(0, 40);
```

If the row height should be set automatically to match the content, configure the `TextPainter` for row height calculation using the appropriate constructor.